# How to trim (cut) UIView in Swift

Tags: swift, xcode, uiview

I made UIView the frame is `x: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width*3, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height`.

When moved to other ViewController by `self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)`, the left side of view is shown during screen transition.
When I set the point to `x:0, y:0`, the screen transition was smooth, didn't show the left side of the view during screen transition.

So I want to cut only the left side of the view before screen transition. How can I do it in Swift?

Comment: Can u provide screenshots of your issue? I think the issue can be because the new view controller to which you are moving have clear color. Try giving some background color(try white) to the new view controller's view

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I tried it but my issue wasn't solved. It's difficult to provide screenshots of my issue because taking the screenshot of the moment of screen transition is so difficult.... When I set the view x to 0 and do popviewcontroller, the screen transition animation is smooth because the view doesn't have any parts on left side. But when I set the view x to 320 (UIScreen.main....width), the view of left side will be shown because the x position is not 0. It's very unnatural to be shown before view's the part of left side...I'm sorry I can't describe my issue.

Comment: Have you tried putting it inside another UIView which is the size of the screen and setting the clipToBounds property on that one to true?

Comment: @UpholderOfTruth Thank you for your advice. It did work! Thank you!

Comment: No worries glad to help.